# audio phase rotation to 180 degree using objective C or C

Tags: ios, audio

For my iOS App, I need to phase shift the audio file to 180 degree. I dont have any idea. Please help me to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process you describe is called inverting the phase. It is accomplished quite easily once you have the sample data. To illustrate:

```
for_each_sample {
  sample[idx] = -sample[idx];
}
```

Your program also needs to check ranges when inverting integer types.

You can use ExtAudioFile or AudioFile APIs to read and write files, and AudioConvertor APIs to convert the sample data to LPCM (which ExtAudioFile can set up for you).

Comment: Thank you, I am having an audio input file, Please can you share me code the code snippet to achieve the above with the audio file

Comment: @Ashok the code samples related to the API `ExtAudioFileDispose` will be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, My audio samples are not in the range -1 to 1. Please help me.

Comment: @Ashok this also works for signed integer. the [-1...1] was not a requirement i specified.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to play the original sound and the phase inverted sound simultaneously, for making the audio to cancel each other, but it does not, both the audio are playing and able to hear the audio. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Ashok if they don't cancel, then something is wrong. so you have to figure out whether one or both of the inputs are delayed, filtered, not synchronized. even if you apply gain to one signal, they will not cancel (proportionate to how much gain you have applied).

Comment: Hi pls can you provide me any sample code which is working for you since i am struggling to get it done.

Comment: i don't have something that i can distribute to you.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Let me explore it.

Answer (score 1):

A phase shift of 180° is a phase invert.  The simplest way to achieve this (assuming your samples are in a -1 to 1 range) is to multiply each sample by -1.

Mike

Comment: Thank you, Please can you share me the sample code snippets for achieving the above in audio file.

Comment: Hi Mike, If my audio samples are not in a range -1 to 1, then what I have to do?

Comment: It depends on the range your samples are in.  If they are in a 0 - 256 range then you need to do something along the lines of
`newval = oldval > 128 : oldval - 128 : oldval + 128;`